# Localnet transaction stuck finalizing

Tags: anchor, solana-cli, anchor-test, solana-test-validator, anchor-client

I attempted to run my test using anchor on Localnet but got my test stuck like this

`⠤ [0/1] Finalizing transaction 3DV4XGaWPQA5Bj2KtoLF28ivwchkD3i4Z8xk5yxYArdRdja7WWXkfTn7MhHjN6LGFEZsAy7KJRk7Kpd4to4dgyE2`

My tests previously passed without a similar issue, and I made no changes before getting this issue.

The same issue occurs when I request for airdrop on Localnet.

I checked a similar GitHub issue over a year ago and it appears the cause has been fixed in future releases. I've used the latest release of Solana and previous stable versions, but it didn't fix the issue.

I have also tried using Rosetta 2, but it did not work.

Does anyone know why this issue suddenly occurred or how I can be able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was restart the local validator by running

`solana-test-validator -r`